# How to find out frequency of each unique elements in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of length 927. Length of each element in the list is unequal. (Please condiser the following example. I have given only first 6 elements of the list)

```
[[1]]
[1] "DIR" "EMERGING" "UNP"      

[[2]]
[1] "DIR" "ECO" "UNP"             

[[3]]
[1] "DIRECT"

[[4]]
[1] "DIR" "ECO" "NATURAL"              

[[5]]
[1] "DIR"

[[6]]
[1] "DIR"
```

My goal is to find out unique elements in the list and count the frequency for each unique elements in the list. Using `unique(list_name)`, I have found out the unique elements in the list. But I am unable to find out the frequency for each unique list element. Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `table()` to do this

Comment: I have tried that. But it is giving error:
table(list_name)
Error in table(list_name) : all arguments must have the same length

Comment: @user3642360 try rather `table(unique(unlist(list_anme)))`

Comment: @agstudy wouldn't that also work without `unique`? (`table(unlist(list_name))`)

Comment: @beginneR maybe :)  or without `unlist` also just using `unique`...

Comment: I want to find the unique path. In my example unique(list_name) will give me the following results:
"DIR" "EMERGING" "UNP"
"DIR" "ECO" "UNP" 
"DIRECT"
"DIR" "ECO" "NATURAL"
"DIR"

and the frequency will be 1,1,1,1,2

Answer (score 4):

Could do (assuming your list called `list_name`)

```
table(unlist(lapply(list_name, paste, collapse = " ")))

## DIR  DIR ECO NATURAL      DIR ECO UNP DIR EMERGING UNP           DIRECT 
##   2                1                1                1                1
```

Comment: I understood the question only after reading your answer :) +1

Comment: I don't seem to get your answer: why is "DIR" counted separately for each top-level `list` element? But then again, I read the OP's question as "how many 'DIR' are there anywhere in my list" so HMMV :-) --- ooops, found his late comment. +1 for you.

Comment: @user3642360, don't forget to accept correct answers to your questions unless you need additional clarification or want to wait for more answers.